# How to install D-Link DWA-510 for Debian 7?

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers

I just bought a D-Link DWA-510. But I can't install it on my Debian 7 32 bits.

And I want to use in a runlevel 3.

How can I use this D-link?

Thanks!

Comment: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=40500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In debian 7 is not possible to use

apt-get install firmware-ralink

by default.

The solution is [here](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/firmware-ralink)

You have to download firmware-ralink and after use dpkg -i in this file.